# jsf navigation pages showing data table

Tags: ajax, jsf, navigation

I'm very new to JSF and Web app. Now I'm developing very basic web app that displays data from database in jsf data table. I'm facing one problem. I have lot of data from database in my List object in managed bean and I wan't to display them 10 by 10 in my data table. For example First time I load page, data table only display first 10 row and then I click link 'next' it displays next 10 so on. So It's also good that they all be in same page. But I don't know how to do it, I guess java script is needed. ps help me...

Comment: It's called "pagination". A lot of component libraries offer this out the box. See e.g. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf

Answer (score 0):

A Possibility is to use a second list. Create a new List, fill it with the first 10 and bind the Datatable to this new list. When Next or Previous is clicked, clear the list and get index 11-20 or whatever from your Original List and fill your second List.